# How to read recursive data structures from String in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types

For example;

```
  data TRAINING=AGAIN Int [TRAINING]
                |RUN
                |JUMP
                |PUNCH Int 
           deriving (Eq,Show,Read)
```

is defined and I want that if the User enters something like:

```
  "RUN, PUNCH 15, AGAIN 3 [JUMP, AGAIN 2 [PUNCH 20]]"
```

then the program should return

```
  [RUN,PUNCH 15,AGAIN 3 [JUMP,AGAIN 2 [PUNCH 20]]]
```

So I wrote

```
  fight :: String->[TRAINING]
  fight xs=[read xs ::TRAINING]
```

but I am getting "no parse Exception". I am novice and I want to know what a "no parse Exception" is and how  I can fix it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A no parse exception means that what you gave Haskell isn't the correct pattern for the instance of `Read`. In this case it's because list's are shown like this:

```
[<show element>,<show element>...]
```

And you're missing the outer brackets. Fixing it is as easy as seeing what the output should be:

```
Prelude> show [RUN,PUNCH 15,AGAIN 3 [JUMP,AGAIN 2 [PUNCH 20]]]
         "[RUN,PUNCH 15,AGAIN 3 [JUMP,AGAIN 2 [PUNCH 20]]]"
```

So you need to surround the whole thing with []'s. Your function is right, you just have a slightly incorrect input string.

If you don't like this restriction, it may be time to just write a simple parser with Parsec or similar. Though this might be a bit challenging if you're totally new to Haskell.

Comment: Spaces around the commas don't hurt, `read` can handle those fine.

Comment: Although I like Parsec, it wouldn't be challenging to write a recursive descent parser by hand for this, just slightly tedious.

Comment: @Wes I'm more thinking of someone who's new enough to haskell they don't know what a no parse exception is. Just getting up and running parsec in the first place would be the most challenging part

Comment: How can i write a recursive descent parser.i am asking for just a little example not the whole code and where should i start to learn parsec

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/Parsing This has an explanation of a scheme parser which is pretty close to the sort of parser you'd be writing. http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html Is more in depth but it expects a bit more knowledge going in.

Answer (score 1):

In other words, following jozefg's answer:

```
fight xs = read xs ::[TRAINING]
```

and also:

```
"[RUN, PUNCH 15, AGAIN 3 [JUMP, AGAIN 2 [PUNCH 20]]]"
```

Comment: but this doesnt fix actually

Comment: @nbdip That's interesting...setting `fight xs = read xs ::[TRAINING]` and typing `fight "[RUN, PUNCH 15, AGAIN 3 [JUMP, AGAIN 2 [PUNCH 20]]]"` is the only way that worked for me, using your data structure. How did you fix it?